# Flight cancelled due to strikes

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, compensation, ryanair, ec261

I was supposed to be flying with RyanAir to Portugal tomorrow. Unfortunately, today I got a message saying that the flight is canceled and a link to ask for the money back.

The problem is that I have booked a night on a hotel and if I can to cancel the booking I need to pay 50 euro which the exact amount I paid for the room.

Truth be told I’m a bit mad from RyanAir because they did this last minute.

Is there a way I can ask for them to refund me the funds of the hotel also ?

Comment: Do you have travel insurance?

Comment: the travel is supposed to be only three day and no insurance since I got one in Germany

Answer (score 1):

If the strike was caused by airline personnel, you can claim compensation according to EC261 rules (https://www.hilldickinson.com/insights/articles/ecj-rules-compensation-payable-sudden-airline-strikes-causing-delaycancellation, http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=201149&pageIndex=0&doclang=en&mode=lst&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=642113). If the strike was caused by airport, ATC or other non-airline personnel, then it's an extraordinary circumstance and the airline does not need to pay compensations.

Besides those compensations, the airline is not responsible for further damages outside of the contract (this might be different if you have booked the hotel as a package with the flight).

Comment: Yes, if it's airline personnel OP is due compensation, and if it's ATC personnel OP isn't. But in between it can be more complex. For instance, if the airline outsources some of their tasks to a ground handling company and there are several at that airport, then it usually counts like airline personnel.

Comment: the booking wasn't done as a package. Regarding the strikeI think it is caued in france and it is probably from the ryanair workers

Comment: If the flight is tomorrow, then it's most likely the French ATC strike from 5th to 7th December. In that case you're out of luck.